# How do you stop search in a loop once you meet the condition

Tags: java

How do you stop the for each loop from proceeding when the condition is false? because I can only let `x = newX` when all the object in the collection is true to the condition. thank you for help. break won't help, I tried.

```
for (char  h : collection){
    if ( condition == false )
    {

    }
    else{
        x = newX;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use break; to exit the loop

Comment: `break` will help. It's the standard way to break out of a loop (hence the name).

Comment: "break won't help, I tried". it does help. if that's not what you want then please explain.

Comment: "when all the object in the collection is true to the condition" <- Can you rephrase what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to use a break statement. But you want to set new x value only when all elements of the list are passing some condition.

```
boolean allMatch = true;
for (char  h : collection) {
    if (!condition) {
        allMatch = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (allMatch) {
    x = newX;
}
```

If you want to check if all element sof a loop are matching some condition you can use java 8 feature:

```
boolean allMatch = list.stream().allMatch(element -> condition);
if (allMatch) {
    x = newX;
}
```

Comment: The line `allMatch = allMatch && condition;` is unnecessary. It would be enough to put `allMatch = condition` or even `allMatch = false` in the first if-statement.

Comment: True, but then, why update the value in each loop? It would be wiser to do it only on condition not matched.

Comment: Which value do you mean? If you mean `allMatch`, that is exactly what I was indicating to avoid. Because **now** it isnt updated any iteration, only at the end (before `break`).

Comment: In the first example I ment that it would be better only to update allMatch variable only if condition would be false. Current answer is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

use `break;` statement to `break` when the if condition is true.

```
for (char h : collection) {
    if (condition == false) {
        break;
    } else {
        x = newX;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can work with a flag if the else block only has to be executed once

```
    boolean test=true;
    for (char h : collection) {
        if (condition == false) {
            test=false;
            break;
        } 
    }
    if(test){
        x=newX;
    }
```

sadly your question is not very clear. maybe you can give an example for the condition and such

Answer (score 0):

The `break` statement exits the loop.

Your example thus looks like this:

```
for (char  h : collection){
     if ( condition == false )
    {
       break;
    }
    else{
        x = newX;
    }
}
```

Read more about the break statement in the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `break;` keyword.

> It will eventually break the loop and exit after the condition is satisfied!